# What is Messenger Queue? is both message queue and messenger queue are same?

Tags: java, android

What is messenger queue in android? is both Message Queue and Messenger Queue are same?

Answer (score -1):

Basically MessageQueue is were a low-level class holding the list of messages to be dispatched by a Looper. Messages are not added directly to a MessageQueue, but rather through Handler objects associated with the Looper.
You can retrieve the MessageQueue for the current thread with Looper#myQueue().

And Messenger in android is reference to a Handler, which others can use to send messages to it. This allows for the implementation of message-based communication across processes, by creating a Messenger pointing to a Handler in one process, and handing that Messenger to another process.

They both are different on concept level.